# Returning an equation from a function

Tags: r, function, return, equation

Can I return an equation from a function?
For example,

```
testfn<-function(x)
{
  y=x+z
  return(y)
}
testfn(2)
```

I want y=2+z

Is there any other way?

Comment: What's `z`? Is it globally defined? Is it an argument of `testfn`? What is the function supposed to return?

Comment: Given that `z` is somewhere defined, what's wrong with the above function?

Comment: I want to return equations which I will eventually use in an optimization function. z will be defined later, it is not a global. For example, I want to use two equation y=2+z and y=1+z, I want to call the testfn(2) and testfn(1). May be return needs to have a number inside.

Comment: `writeLines(paste("y = ", x, " + z", sep = "", collapse = "\n"))` before the return statement

Comment: Okay, I am trying to maximize a likelihood function. The utility is quite complicated and the equation changes by brand. I thought I can define a function which returns utility by brand and my likelihood function will only have model parameters. I do understand that I can define everything inside likelihood function. But I was trying to make it clean.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. R is not a computer algebra system. If `z` is a parameter you need to define it as a function parameter.

Comment: your function argument's is `x` but you have `z` as well so it will keep giving you error. please edit your question with what you try and some data. That will help us to help you.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was trying to explore some options where I can return equations from function.

Comment: Someone, can post an answer saying "You need to return numbers/vectors/matrices. You cannot return equations, as they have unknowns"

Comment: You *can* return formulas, if that helps at all: `testfn <- function(x) return(as.formula(paste("y ~", x, "+ z", sep = " ")))`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are looking for `substitute`:

```
testfn <- function(x) {
  substitute(y <- x + z, environment())
}
z <- 1
e <- testfn(2)
#y <- 2 + z
eval(e)
y
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
testfn<-function(x)
{
  y = paste0("y=",x,"+z")
  return(y)
}
testfn(2)

[1] "y=2+z"
```

Comment: Sorry, not this. Thanks for effort though.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question, but if you want to return a *function* from a function, it would be something like the following.

```
testfn <- function(x){
    force(x)
    function(z) x + z
}

y <- testfn(2)
y(3)
#[1] 5
```

If you are not at all interested in this just say so and I'll delete this answer.